# failed to insert data from android to mysql using php

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I'm trying to insert data from android to mysql using php. there's no error but the data was not inserted to my mysql table and it shows "Insert Data Failed!".

here's my java class

```
package com.ta.nutrifact;



import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DaftarAkun extends Activity {
    TextView tekserror;
    private EditText txtNama, txtPass2, txtPass, txtBerat, txtTinggi, txtAF, txtUsia, txtGula, txtTekanan, txtKolestrol, txtAsamUrat, txtJK ;
    EditText email;
    private String url = "http://10.0.2.2/TA/adduser.php";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.daftar_akun);
        tekserror = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showError);
        txtPass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPassword);
        txtPass2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPasswordAgain);
        txtPass2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (!s.toString().equals(txtPass.getText().toString()) ) {
                    tekserror.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    tekserror.setText("Password Tidak Cocok");
                } else {
                    tekserror.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

            }
        });


        txtNama = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputUsername);
        txtTinggi = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputTinggi);
        txtUsia = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputUsia);


        Button btnSimpan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSimpan);
        // daftarkan even onClick pada btnSimpan
            btnSimpan.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    try {
                        // setiap parameter yang akan dikirim melalui http
                    // harus encode agar
                        // dapat terbaca dengan baik oleh server
                        String nama = URLEncoder.encode(txtNama.getText()
                                .toString(), "utf-8");
                        String pass = URLEncoder.encode(txtPass.getText()
                               .toString(), "utf-8");
                        String tinggi = URLEncoder.encode(txtTinggi.getText()
                                .toString(), "utf-8");
                        String usia = URLEncoder.encode(txtUsia.getText()
                               .toString(), "utf-8");

                        url += "?nama=" + nama + "&pass=" + pass + "&tinggi=" + tinggi + "&usia=" + usia ;
                        getRequest(url);
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

            }
            });

    }
    public void getRequest(String Url) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Insert Data " + Url + " ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            Toast.makeText(this, "Insert Data" + request(response) + " ",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Insert Data Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }

    }

public static String request(HttpResponse response) {
        String result = "";

    try {
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(in));
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                str.append(line + "\n");
            }
            in.close();
            result = str.toString();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            result = "Error";
        }
        return result;
    }
    }
```

the adduser.php

```
<?php
$nama = $_GET['nama'];
$pass = $_GET['pass'];
$tinggi = $_GET['tinggi'];
$usia = $_GET['usia'];


$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");

if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('tugas_akhir', $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO login (username, password) VALUES ('$nama', '$pass')");


mysql_query("INSERT INTO data_user (username, tinggi_badan,usia)
VALUES ('$nama','$tinggi' , '$usia')");


mysql_close($con);
?>
```

daftar_akun.xml

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#99cc00"
    android:scrollbarSize="1dp" >

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15.9dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:background="@drawable/registrasi_utama_hdpi"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/showError"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
            android:background="@drawable/registrasi_hdpi_error"
            android:paddingLeft="43dp"
            android:paddingRight="9dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputUsername"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="26.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15.41dp"
            android:background="@drawable/registrasi_hdpi_username"
            android:hint="Masukkan Username"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:maxLength="8"
            android:paddingLeft="43dp"
            android:paddingRight="9dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputPassword"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="26.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:background="@drawable/registrasi_hdpi_password"
            android:hint="Masukkan Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLength="8"
            android:paddingLeft="43dp"
            android:paddingRight="9dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputPasswordAgain"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="26.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:background="@drawable/registrasi_hdpi_password"
            android:hint="Ulangi Password  "
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:maxLength="8"
            android:paddingLeft="43dp"
            android:paddingRight="9dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="26.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/showTanggal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/registrasi_hdpi_calendar"
                android:hint="Tanggal Lahir"
                android:paddingLeft="43dp"
                android:paddingRight="9dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="14dp" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffffff"
                android:src="@drawable/registrasi_hdpi_calendar_edit" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="26.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/buttonAddHealth"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#ffffffff"
                android:src="@drawable/registrasi_hdpi_health" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Klik untuk Riwayat Penyakit "
                android:paddingLeft="43dp"
                android:paddingRight="9dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="14dp" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="26.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/registrasi_hdpi_22"
            android:hint="Isi Jika Sudah Pernah Check "
            android:maxLength="8"
            android:paddingLeft="43dp"
            android:paddingRight="9dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="14dp" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputTinggi"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="26.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:background="@drawable/registrasi_hdpi_24"
            android:hint="Tinggi Badan"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="8"
            android:paddingLeft="43dp"
            android:paddingRight="9dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inputUsia"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="26.5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="11dp"
            android:background="@drawable/registrasi_hdpi_24"
            android:hint="Usia"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="8"
            android:paddingLeft="43dp"
            android:paddingRight="9dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="14dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/teksNama"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <Button android:text="Sign Up" android:id="@+id/btnSimpan"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

    </LinearLayout>



</ScrollView>
```

thanks for your help

Comment: Can you show Logcat error?

Comment: This does not answer your question, but please think about what happens if someone's username or password has a ' in it.

Comment: Please User `mysqli_*` or `PDO` for better security from SQL Injection attack. `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Comment: Also, try logging/printing `ex.errorMessage()` at `Toast.makeText(this, "Insert Data Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: @Ravi I got "null" from the ex.errorMessage(). can't seem to figure out why. updated with my xml file

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Maybe my answer is wrong. But I had the same problem when I use the URL

```
private String url = "http://10.0.2.2/TA/adduser.php";
```

Then I changed the format likeas

```
private static String url  = "http://192.168.137.1:81/TA/adduser.php";
```

Then I was work properly. Again I am saying I don't know my answer is correct or wrong. But try this as well.

Comment: 192.168.137.1:81 This is your pc ip address